# OrientDB clustered mode not working: quorum not reached, etc

Tags: distributed, orientdb

It seems I simply can't get clustered mode to work properly with OrientDB 2.1.9 GA.

Here's how I set up my 3 servers:
 1. Install OrientDB on all 3 of them
 2. Initialize my database on the first (master) server. It's an SQL script that creates all my vertex and edge classes, indexes, etc.
 3. Update the distributed configuration/hazelcast.xml on the first (master) server and restart it with dserver.sh
 4. Update the distributed configuration/hazelcast.xml on the other servers and restart them with dserver.sh

The servers talk to each other and I can see that the first server transfers the database to the other two.

I can access the OrientDB studio on all 3 IP addresses but the queries run extremely slowly, and upon closer inspection I see errors in the shell output. Running my code to create new records, I run into further errors.

Here's a sample of the messages I see in the shell:

```
2016-01-26 13:58:12:445 WARNI [node1453810302941] timeout (9004ms) on waiting for synchronous responses from nodes=[node1453812260180, node1453810302941, node14
53812479735] responsesSoFar=[] request=id=85 from=node1453810302941 task=record_read(#11:0) [OHazelcastDistributedDatabase]
2016-01-26 13:58:12:445 WARNI [node1453810302941] no response received from local node about request id=85 from=node1453810302941 task=record_read(#11:0) [ODistributedResponseManager]
2016-01-26 13:58:12:446 WARNI [node1453810302941] detected 3 node(s) in timeout or in conflict and quorum (2) has not been reached, rolling back changes for request (id=85 from=node1453810302941 task=record_read(#11:0)) [ODistributedResponseManager]
2016-01-26 13:58:12:446 WARNI [node1453810302941] Quorum 2 not reached for request (id=85 from=node1453810302941 task=record_read(#11:0)). Elapsed=9018ms No server in conflict. Received: {node1453812260180=waiting-for-response, node1453810302941=waiting-for-response, node1453812479735=waiting-for-response} [ODistributedResponseManager]
```

As for the errors raised in Java, this is what I get:

```
26-Jan-2016 21:37:15.093 SEVERE [http-nio-8084-exec-14] com.orientechnologies.common.log.OLogManager.log Error on fetching record during browsing. The record has been skipped
 com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on retrieving record #11:0 (cluster: account)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1849)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionOptimistic.loadRecord(OTransactionOptimistic.java:243)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.load(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1592)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.load(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:121)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.OIdentifiableIterator.readCurrentRecord(OIdentifiableIterator.java:287)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.iterator.ORecordIteratorClusters.hasNext(ORecordIteratorClusters.java:160)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.impls.orient.OrientElementIterator.hasNext(OrientElementIterator.java:46)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.DefaultGraphQuery$DefaultGraphQueryIterable$1.loadNext(DefaultGraphQuery.java:119)
    at com.tinkerpop.blueprints.util.DefaultGraphQuery$DefaultGraphQueryIterable$1.hasNext(DefaultGraphQuery.java:95)
    at gamble.user.account.persistence.OrientDbAccountPersistence.emailAddressExists(OrientDbAccountPersistence.java:172)
    at gamble.user.account.operation.CreateUserAccount$3.execute(CreateUserAccount.java:315)
    at gamble.operation.Operation.execute(Operation.java:216)
    at gamble.web.servlet.page.UserSignUpForm.doPost(UserSignUpForm.java:126)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:644)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:725)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:301)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.netbeans.modules.web.monitor.server.MonitorFilter.doFilter(MonitorFilter.java:393)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at gamble.web.filter.InitializationFilter.doFilter(InitializationFilter.java:134)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:239)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:219)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:136)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:74)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:610)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:516)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1015)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:652)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11NioProtocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11NioProtocol.java:222)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1575)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1533)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.core.exception.ODatabaseException: Error on retrieving record #11:0 (cluster: account)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1879)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.tx.OTransactionNoTx.loadRecord(OTransactionNoTx.java:86)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.load(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1611)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.readRecord(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:1649)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.ONetworkProtocolBinary.executeRequest(ONetworkProtocolBinary.java:357)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.network.protocol.binary.OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.execute(OBinaryNetworkProtocolAbstract.java:223)
    at com.orientechnologies.common.thread.OSoftThread.run(OSoftThread.java:77)
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Error on executing distributed request (id=8 from=node1453810302941 task=record_read(#11:0) user=#5:0) against database 'gamble.[account]' to nodes [node1453810302941, node1453812260180, node1453812479735]
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.send2Nodes(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:189)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastPlugin.sendRequest(OHazelcastPlugin.java:367)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedStorage.readRecord(ODistributedStorage.java:630)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx$SimpleRecordReader.readRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:3224)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.core.db.document.ODatabaseDocumentTx.executeReadRecord(ODatabaseDocumentTx.java:1844)
    ... 6 more
Caused by: com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedException: Quorum 2 not reached for request (id=8 from=node1453810302941 task=record_read(#11:0) user=#5:0). Elapsed=9039ms No server in conflict. Received: {node1453812260180=waiting-for-response, node1453810302941=waiting-for-response, node1453812479735=waiting-for-response}
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedResponseManager.manageConflicts(ODistributedResponseManager.java:570)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.distributed.ODistributedResponseManager.getFinalResponse(ODistributedResponseManager.java:339)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.waitForResponse(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:423)
    at com.orientechnologies.orient.server.hazelcast.OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.send2Nodes(OHazelcastDistributedDatabase.java:186)
    ... 10 more
```

As a side note, in my distributed-config.json, current value for readQuorum is "1". For 3 servers, I assume I need to set it to "2" to guarantee not reading stale values?

Comment: Which version of OrientDb are you using ?

Comment: @AlessandroRota updated my question. Using OrientDB 2.1.9 GA

Comment: Read quorum shouldn't have anything to do with consistency of data.
The docs suggest the setting for write quorum should be N/2+1, where N is the number of nodes. 

http://orientdb.com/docs/last/Distributed-Configuration.html